# Show Hide Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following button:

```
<a href="#" class="see-more">See more <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

When clicked it will toggle a div for show/hide effect. Got that part working okay. However, I realized I'm going to need this on multiple buttons. I believe I need to refactor my current code to be a function, but I'm not too sure where to go from here.

This is what I started with:

```
// Slide toggle content
$(".see-more").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $(".show-more").slideToggle('slow');

  if($(this).html() == 'See less <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>') {
    $(this).html('See more <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
  } else {
     $(this).html('See less <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
  }
});
```

My first attempt didn't yield much luck

```
var seeMore = $('.see-more');

function showHide() {

    this.preventDefault();

    $(".show-more").slideToggle('slow');

    if($(this).html() == 'See less <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>') {
      $(this).html('See more <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
    } else {
      $(this).html('See less <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
    }
}

seeMore.click(showHide);
```

EDIT: Adding more code for reference on how this is working (or should work)

```
    <!-- Agenda Module -->
            <div class="row module">
              <div class="small-12 columns">
                <div class="radius bordered">
                  <img src="path-to-image" alt="">
                  <div class="module-content">
                    <h2>Agenda</h2>
                    <ul class="no-bullet agenda-list">
                      <li class="agenda-date">Friday 11th September</li>
                      <li><span class="agenda-time">19.00</span>Welcome Party</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="no-bullet agenda-list">
                      <li class="agenda-date">Saturday 12th September</li>
                      <li><span class="agenda-time">09.45</span>Brunch</li>
                      <div class="show-more agenda-show">
                      <li><span class="agenda-time">10.10</span>Meet the players</li>
                      <li><span class="agenda-time">10.30</span>Driving range and puttin tuition</li>
                      <li><span class="agenda-time">11.30</span>Tee-Off</li>
                      <li><span class="agenda-time">13.15</span>Lunch at the Club house</li>
                      <li><span class="agenda-time">17.00</span>End of play</li>
                      <li><span class="agenda-time">19.30</span>Drinks reception</li>
                      <li><span class="agenda-time">21.30</span>Guest speaker</li>
                      </div>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="see-more show-for-small">See more <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END Agenda Module -->
```

Additional example (In this example I would be adding more rows that are hide/show -- currently not there in my code, adding for reference)

```
<li>
                <div class="radius bordered">
                  <img src="http://images.response.vodafoneglobalenterprise.com/EloquaImages/clients/VodafoneGroupPLC/{ab3c73da-3765-4fc5-abac-b2a9db4db779}_mod-banner-contact.png" alt="">
                  <div class="module-content">
                    <h2>Get in touch</h2>
                    <div class="row mar-bot-15">
                      <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <p>Contact us to find out more about this or any other events that Vodafone organise:</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row collapse mar-bot-15">
                      <div class="small-3 columns text-center">
                        <img src="http://images.response.vodafoneglobalenterprise.com/EloquaImages/clients/VodafoneGroupPLC/{76cda4ed-0939-4509-bda4-10fa7307a2cf}_icn-mail.png" alt="" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="small-9 columns">
                        <p><strong>events@vodafone.co.uk</strong></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row collapse mar-bot-15">
                      <div class="small-3 columns text-center">
                        <img src="http://images.response.vodafoneglobalenterprise.com/EloquaImages/clients/VodafoneGroupPLC/{b8c7c4b3-9ab4-4b86-add3-c0c5b936ae41}_icn-phone.png" alt="">
                      </div>
                      <div class="small-9 columns">
                        <p><strong>+44 (0)1635 33251</strong></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="show-more">
                    <!-- hide / show content here-->
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="see-more">See more <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
              </li>
```

I can see how one of the answers would work in this example .. I will try to restructure the original HTML ... the agenda module is different, slightly, than the other modules. The "show more >" link will only show up on mobile for that example.

Comment: You can use DOM traversal to relate the clicked `a` element to the required `.show-more` element. Can you edit your question to include a sample of that HTML.

Comment: it is a class so you can reuse it on any part of the code which you give the class="see-more" need more detail to know how you want to reuse it so i can get the understanding in how you want it to work

Comment: `this.preventDefault()` won't work. This is a function of an event, but `this` is the DOM element you clicked on.

Comment: How are the `see-more` links and `show-more` DIVs related in the HTML?

Comment: .see-more on click will slideToggle .show-more div .... its going to be reused on other buttons in the layout. So when I click one right now, it's doing it to all of them

Comment: Added more code for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slightly restructure your HTML, and then use `.prev()` to find the closest DIV to the clicked button.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1fpp5xkr/)</kbd>

Note that SlideToggle will work great when you only have a single expanding DIV to keep track of. Once you have multiple DIVs, any of which can be expanded/contracted, you should explicitly specify the slideUp / slideDown functions.

```js
$(".see-more").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  if($(this).html() == 'See less <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>') {
    $(this).html('See more <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
     $(this).prev(".show-more").slideUp('slow');
  } else {
     $(this).html('See less <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
     $(this).prev(".show-more").slideDown('slow');
  }
});
```

```css
.show-more{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Agenda Module -->
<div class="row module">
 <div class="small-12 columns">
  <div class="radius bordered">
   <img src="path-to-image" alt="">
   <div class="module-content">
    <h2>Agenda</h2>
    <ul class="no-bullet agenda-list">
     <li class="agenda-date">Friday 11th September</li>
     <li><span class="agenda-time">19.00</span>Welcome Party</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="no-bullet agenda-list">
     <li class="agenda-date">Saturday 12th September</li>
     <li><span class="agenda-time">09.45</span>Brunch</li>
     <div class="show-more agenda-show">
      <li><span class="agenda-time">10.10</span>Meet the players</li>
      <li><span class="agenda-time">10.30</span>Driving range and puttin tuition</li>
      <li><span class="agenda-time">11.30</span>Tee-Off</li>
      <li><span class="agenda-time">13.15</span>Lunch at the Club house</li>
      <li><span class="agenda-time">17.00</span>End of play</li>
      <li><span class="agenda-time">19.30</span>Drinks reception</li>
      <li><span class="agenda-time">21.30</span>Guest speaker</li>
     </div>
    <a href="#" class="see-more show-for-small">See more <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </ul>
    <ul class="no-bullet agenda-list">
     <li class="agenda-date">Sunday 13th September</li>
     <li><span class="agenda-time">08.30</span>Breakfast</li>
     <div class="show-more agenda-show">
      <li><span class="agenda-time">10.30</span>Meet at Lobby for Bus</li>
      <li><span class="agenda-time">11.00</span>Church service</li>
      <li><span class="agenda-time">12.30</span>Bus leaves church</li>
      <li><span class="agenda-time">13.15</span>Lunch at the Club house</li>
      <li><span class="agenda-time">17.00</span>Dinner at the Club house</li>
      <li><span class="agenda-time">19.00</span>Free Evening</li>
     </div>
    <a href="#" class="see-more show-for-small">See more <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- END Agenda Module -->
```

Comment: The layout needs the button where it is -- (screenshot) https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bbs6fezuq0fii7/Screenshot%202015-07-01%2017.21.05.png?dl=0

But this does give me some ideas

Comment: You can use css to reposition the button. Suggestion: accept an answer to this question, ask a new question just about positioning the button. Instead of two or three people (who are following this question) trying to help, you will get dozens/hundreds of new readers. Much faster answers. Your screenshot did not display - try a free anon image hosting repository such as tinypic.com or postimage.com, imgur.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to refactor your code to a function.

You can still use:

```
$(".see-more").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  if($(this).hasClass(".show-more")) {
    $(this).slideToggle('slow');
  }

  if($(this).html() == 'See less <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>') {
    $(this).html('See more <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
  } else {
    $(this).html('See less <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that the selector you amended to `this` was `.show-more` not `.see-more`.

Comment: Oh sorry I have missed that one, I have update my example.

Comment: I think the idea is that they're two different elements. `see-more` is a link that you click on, and it shows a `show-more` DIV somewhere.

Comment: Like in SO when there are lots of comments, you have to click on a link to see them all.

Comment: .see-more on click will slideToggle .show-more div .... its going to be reused on other buttons in the layout. So when I click one right now, it's doing it to all of them

Comment: As I understand it right, the "Agenda Module" is gona be like a module. You should be possible to have one to more "Agenda Module"?

Comment: the link with the class of .see-more lives outside of the container div for elements I need to show/hide. Added sample code in OP